# Custom serialization with Ehcache

Tags: java, serialization, ehcache

Is it possible to tell Ehcache to use a custom serialization when moving an object from the memory to the disc or off-heap cache and the other way? I want to skip some fields from serialization which are not declared transient (third-party-library) but which I do not need to store since I can easily recalculate them. I want to do this to save quite some memory. At best, I want to use a library like Kryo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by using wrappers and by adding another abstraction layer, a `SerializationWrapper`. The wrapper presented here uses Kryo:

```
final class SerializationWrapper implements Serializable {

  private final static Kryo KRYO = new Kryo();
  private Object object;

  public SerializationWrapper(Object object) {
    this.object = object;
  }

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) 
      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Input input = new Input(objectInputStream);
    object = KRYO.readClassAndObject(input);
    input.close();
  }

  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream) 
      throws IOException {
    Output output = new Output(objectOutputStream);
    KRYO.writeClassAndObject(output, object);
    output.close();
  }

  public Object getWrappedObject() {
    return object;
  }
}
```

The serialization methods `readObject` and `writeObject`will be called [by the Java contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and allow me to implement a custom serialization. Additionally, This solution does not create a size overhead since I only write the wrapped object to the output stream and skip the writing of the wrapper entirely. You can also [read this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) for more info what helped me a lot.

Comment: where is the output/input import?

Comment: They are defined at `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io` package